# How to enable feedback of status bar in Meego apps?

Tags: qt, qml, meego

I'm developing a Meego app. I found that in my app, there is no feedback when I click the top status bar. But when I click again to fold the status bar, there is a click sound feed back. Why is this happening? How can I enable feedback for the status bar?

Thanks!